# Bash script whitespace compliant

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, whitespace, exiftool

I have an huge amount of file to organize, they are a JPG files in an absurd folders structure.

I need to move all files from its actual position to an organized folder structure, saving its actually position as EXIF comment because in path there information to preserve.

For example I have a file with this path:

/OLD ARCHIVE/ORGANIZATION 1/1 FANTASTIC EVENT/1995 PIPPO does something.jpg

The destination will be something like:
Archive Digital/AA/1995_BB_000002.jpg

My idea is to run the script from the OLD ARCHIVE/ path in order to have all information in the fname var.
Then extract information from fname var and put them in exif (and in path), at the end, move the file logging what I'm doing.

I am writing this in bash, it was working but had some problem with whitespace management, so I tried to make it whitespace compliant...but it is not working anymore.

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Parametri: CartellaOriginale CartellaOutput Prefisso NumeroIniziale Keywords
filenamePrefix="$3"
filenameNumber=$(printf "%05d" $4)
data=$(date +%F)
filelog="fileMovedLog_$data.txt"
CommonKeywords="$5"
echo "DEV Working on $1"
echo "DEV output folder $2"
echo "DEV filename start $filenamePrefix$filenameNumber"
echo "$1/$filelog"
echo "Backup in ${1%\/}_BAK/"
#echo "$data"
read -p "Press enter to continue"
echo 'Backup in corso'
#cp -R "$1" "${1%\/}_BAK/"
echo 'Backup terminato, inizio elaborazione'
#mkdir "$2"
touch "$1/$filelog"
find "$1" -name "*.jpg" -or -name "*.JPG" -type f -not -path "*_BAK"| while read fname; do
    echo "$fname"
#Chiedo l'anno
    forseAnno=$(echo `grep -oP  '(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)' <<< "$fname"`)
    if [ -z "$forseAnno" ]
    then 
        forseAnno='ND'
    fi
    echo "Inserire cartella anno dove inserire la foto oppure lasciare vuoto se $forseAnno"
    read annoIn </dev/tty

    if [ -z "$annoIn" ]
    then #Se input è vuoto
        anno="$forseAnno"
    else #ho input, metto lì.
        anno="$annoIn"
    fi
    
    #echo "$anno"   
#Keyword per Lightroom
    #Estraggo alcune possibili KeyWord
    string=${fname,,}
    extraKey=''
    if grep -q 'palio' <<< "$string"; then
        extraKey=',palio del niballo'
    fi
    if grep -q 'dama' <<< "$string"; then
        extraKey="${extraKey},dama"
    fi
    if grep -q 'not' <<< "$string"; then
        extraKey="${extraKey},nott de biso"
    fi
    if grep -q 'cavaliere' <<< "$string"; then
        extraKey="${extraKey},cavaliere"
    fi
    if grep -q 'bigorda' <<< "$string"; then
        extraKey="${extraKey},bigorda"
    fi
    if grep -q 'corteo' <<< "$string"; then
        extraKey="${extraKey},corteo"
    fi
    if grep -q 'paggi' <<< "$string"; then
        extraKey="${extraKey},paggi"
    fi
    echo "$extraKey"
    read -e -p "Correggere le Keywords: " -i "$anno,$CommonKeywords$extraKey" KEYWORD </dev/tty
    suffix=$(printf "%05d" $filenameNumber)
    exiftool -p -Keywords='"$KEYWORD $fname"' -overwrite_original
#Registro il precedente nome file nella descrizione
    exiftool -p -Description+=\''ERA: "$fname"'\' "$fname" -overwrite_original  
    
#Sistemo la CreateDate
    echo `exiftool -wm cg -CreateDate=\'"$anno":01:01 00:00:00\' -overwrite_original "$fname"`
    if [ $? -ne 0 ] #avevo già una data
    then
        datafile=(exiftool -S -createdate "$fname")
        while true 
        do 
            if [ $anno -lt 2021 ] #la scrittura della data in EXIF la faccio solo se è un anno minore di 2021. Se ho messo 5060 per indicare anni 50-60 non lo metto
            then 
                    read -e -p "Sovrascrivere la data $datafile con $anno?[Yes/No/Vuoto]" -i "Y" yn </dev/tty
            else
                    read -e -p "Sovrascrivere la data $datafile con $anno?[Yes/No/Vuoto]" -i "N" yn </dev/tty
            fi
            case $yn in 
                [Yy]* ) exiftool -p -CreateDate=\'"$anno":01:01 00:00:00\' -overwrite_original;break;;
                [Nn]* ) break;; #Non fo una sega
                [0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]* ) exiftool -p -CreateDate=\'"$yn":01:01 00:00:00\' -overwrite_original;break;;
                * ) echo "Inserire Y[es]/N[o] o l'anno";;
            esac
        done
    fi
#Procedo allo spostamento e logging
    echo 'Sposto '"$fname $2/$anno/$filenamePrefix$suffix.jpg"
    read -p "Confermi?"
    mv \""$fname"\" \""$2/$anno/$filenamePrefix$suffix.jpg"\"
    echo "\"$fname\"; \"$filenamePrefix$suffix.jpg\"" >>$1/$filelog
    ((filenameNumber++))
    echo ""
done
echo "Completato";
```

Comment: In general Super User is not for code review. There is [another SE site especially for this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) and I can see they review Bash code. Here we want to solve one specific problem per question. You should provide [mcve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367019/10765659): minimal code, example input data (directory tree layout, if relevant; exact command line with arguments; etc.), Bash version. Then: how does the code fail? is there an error message? what is it?  [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) is your friend. "Doesn't work. Help" is not a good question.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know Shellcheck and CodeReview.

Comment: Thanks. 

I fixed almost all the script, just a last problem... some of filename includes quotes, doublequotes and other shit... how I can manage them?

Comment: See [BashFAQ #20: "How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) In this case, one of the key things is to use `find ... -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file ...` BTW, your `find` expression won't work right because of the precedence of `-or`. You can use `-name "*.[Jj][Pp][Gg]"` or, if your `find` supports it, `-iname "*.jpg"`